# Add shared Outlook Calendar to Evolution

Tags: import, outlook, calendar, shared

I'm trying to add a shared Calendar from Outlook to Evolution (3.36.5-0ubuntu1). The person who shared did send me an invitation which contains a xml-file but there is no easy “add calendar”-button. I do not want to receive the entrys that are right now in there but want the calendar to synced (like it would be if I added it in Outlook).
I tried “Subscribe to folder of other EWS user." but I don’t want to add the persons normal calendar but one he created. If I a an ID I see in the xml-file as folder name I get an error “Id is malformed”.